# Java comparing same String returns false

Tags: java, android

Flagged for deletion. Please mod this.

Comment: `substring(0, 2)` ? The returned string has length 2.

Comment: it might be the view hiding zero length characters, do `trim()` and `length()` to ensure there is no hidden character present

Comment: This assumes that `symbol == line.substring(0,2)`. Is  that the case?

Comment: Hint: `symbol` isn't a literal `"#"` and `substring(0, 2)` doesn't have that value either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `symbol.trim()` in order to remove any leading or trailing spaces/empty characters.

You should also not be using `substring(0, 2)` if all you want is one character. `substring(0, 1)` would be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String symbol = null;
if(line != null) {
    //To extract first character of line
    symbol = line.trim().subString(0,1);
}
```